# CSV writer cannot write List of objects

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I use CSV writer and it work great for most part. When I try to write the object which has a list, it ignores writing the list only.
for eg.below, it writes all the attributes of the Trade object except the Wave which is a List of Wave objects

my class trade has following including a list Wave.

```
     class Trade
    {
        public string  symbol { get; set; }
        public bool isOpen { get; set; }
        public DateTime OpenTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }
        public double mfe { get; set; }
        public double mae { get; set; }
        public double entryPrice { get; set; }
        public double exitprice { get; set; }
        public TradeP TradeSignal { get; set; }
        public string  comments { get; set; }
        public int  Days2Stop { get; set; }
        public double TimeBreakout { get; set; }
        public double r { get; set; }
        public int  daysreach1r { get; set; }
        public int daysreach9x50 { get; set; }
        public double maetill1r { get; set; }
        public bool Day1ClosedDown { get; set; }
        public List<Wave> Waves { get; set; }

    }
     // write all the trade objects
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "traderesults.txt", true))
            {
                var csv = new CsvWriter(file);
                csv.WriteRecords(Trades);

            }
```

[image]

In the screenshot above, you can see the csv writer prints all the object attributes. its pretty long but at the end it does not print the attribute of the Wave objects

Comment: What is expected output you want?

Comment: as you can see from the partial screenshot, the csvwriter prints the attributes of the Trade object. it just does not print the attributes of the Wave list which is the part of the Trade Object

Comment: Think, his question was about the expected format for the wave list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV file is flat. How would you represent such record, if you had to create a file manually. You would have to repeat records. Which does not make sense, so library is doing a right thing here by ignoring `Waves`.

Workaround would be to have another property in your class that returns you the comma separated values for a property in `Wave` object, say `Prop1` (`string`).

```
class Trade {
  //..
  public string WaveCSV {
    get {
      return string.Join(",", Waves.Select(w => w.Prop1).ToArray()); 
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to qualify `WaveCSV` with `"` so that comma within the value doesn't harm, or use a different separator altogether.

**Edit**:

If you need more than one property, then you can override `ToString()` in `Wave` class, return whatever you want, and use `w.ToString()` instead.